# Parsing numeric array held inside associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have been dealing with such arrays before and never faced any problem but this time i do not know why it is freaking me out. I am not able to parse the array below.

```
'medias' => array
(
    0 => ''
    1 => array
    (
        'filename' => '1140_image.png'
        'path' => 'path/of/file/here'
        'width' => '1140'
        'height' => '480'
    )
    2 => array
    (
        'filename' => '1140jpg.jpg'
        'path' => 'path/of/file/here'
        'width' => '1140'
        'height' => '713'
    )
)
```

In order to parse it, this is what i am doing

```
foreach($componentModelMedias['medias'] as $componentModelMedia){
    echo $componentModelMedia['path'];
}
```

And it is not showing me any data in return. I am not sure why it is happening and i also know it is not worth asking this question here but tell me if i am doing any thing wrong.

Comment: your first `$componentModelMedia` has a string and not a array as value, so your code will fail in your first iteration

Comment: You should add an `if(is_array($componentModelMedia))` since your `0` element is a string.

Comment: Could you add a `print_r($componentModelMedias['medias'])` before the foreach() line and a `print_r($componentModelMedia)` before the echo?

Comment: Thank you @RocketHazmat - Your solution worked. I missed to check if it is array.